# Highschool trig limit $\lim_{x\to0} (\sin(x))^{\cot^2(x) }$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0} (\sin(x))^{\cot^2(x) }$$

simply putting in the calculator gives not defined and seeing its graph we can clearly say its not defined but I still want to see the whole solving process. I also asked my teacher he said its not solvable.

Comment: This is of the form of a number very near zero raised to a *very large* number.  It will be zero.

Comment: You can show the logarithm tends to infinity with some simple algebra and therefore this limit is either 0 or infinity as a way to get intuition on the problem.

Comment: You could get into issues on the left-hand side of $0$ (i.e. approaching from below), depending on how exactly limits are defined for you (high school math likes to do things more difficult than they have to be in the name of simplification).

Answer (score 2):

If $x<0$ then $\sin x<0.$ If $\cot^2 x$ is irrational, we are trying to take an irrational power of a negative number, which is undefined. The limit does not exist.

Comment: Depends on how you define limits, and what exactly you mean by $(\sin x)^{\cot^2 x}$. But I agree that this is likely why the teacher said it's not solvable.

Answer (score 1):

There's a standard trick here, but it gets messy if you aren't careful.

The main problem is that $\sin(x)^{\cot^2(x)}$ might not be defined for small, negative $x$. In that case, $\sin(x)$ will be negative, and you can't always raise a negative number to any power you want without doing something complicated. If we're happy using one-sided limits, then our trick will work.

If $\sin(x)^{\cot^2(x)}$ has a nonzero limit from the right at $0$, then so does

$$L(x) = \ln \sin(x)^{\cot^2(x)}.$$

This function is only defined where it makes sense. In this case that's for small, positive $x$.

Using the properties of the logarithm,

$$L(x) = \cot^2(x) \ln \sin(x) = \frac{\ln \sin(x)}{\tan^2(x)}.$$

As $x \to 0$ from the right, this is a limit of the form $-\infty / 0$, which comes out to $-\infty$ since $\tan^2(x)$ is positive near $0$. Thus,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(x)^{\cot^2(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{L(x)} = e^{-\infty} = 0.$$

So from the right, $\sin(x)^{\cot^2(x)}$ approaches $0$. But from the left it's mostly meaningless.